# Reduce number of device power supplies

Tags: power-supply, power, device

I have three 5 V DC, 1 ampere devices running from three separate standard manufacturers 240 V power supplies.

Can I connect the three devices in parallel to a single 5 V, 5 ampere power supply?

Comment: It all depends on whether the design of the power supplies support parallel operation.  There have been a number of questions and discussion on this topic recently.  Did you search using tags?

Comment: Delends. Please draw a block diagram of what you have.

Comment: Hi, spent all morning on google with no joy to my question. I would have thought that many would like a simple solution to combining many separate power supplies to one. I have emailed the manufacturer but yet to hear, it can wait no mad rush but thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 2):

In an ideal world, no problem.

In practice, there are several points to check before doing so:

- Does your 3 devices need to be insulated from each other (if there is no connection at all between the devices, or if they share a common ground, then you are probably fine). If you have some exotic connexions (for example the "ground" of one device connected to the +5V of another device, then it is a no go)
- Is the voltage regulator of your 5A supply stable enough for each of your devices (some devices need high quality regulators, other can work with quite bad regulation)
- Does one of your devices generate noise on the supply that might be a problem for the other ones? (that one is hard to check, excepted if you have a scope). If you have switching converters or motors, then I would strongly advice further reflexion on this point (so we would need to know the exact devices)
- Is one of these devices critical? If so, a problem on one device might damage or disable all 3 of them.
- is the total current ALLWAYS within the allowed 5A (some devices require more current at some instants (for example power on, change of state, ...) : it seems the 3 initial supplies manage it, but will the 5A supply manage the power-on current of all 3 devices at the same time?
- Does one of your devices have requirements about power-on voltage ramp? If so, not sure your 5A supply will respect this specific ramp.